# How to fix ENOSPC error while running cypress?

Tags: terminal, cypress

get some error called ESPONC from the terminal on Linux after running cypress by the command "npm run cy:open-mobile"

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert, but from a quick search on Google I saw that it may indicate that your disk is full (read ENOSPC as "Error - no space").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Cypress are you on? 3.3.2 fixed some problems that could cause ENOSPC: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-3-2

Users have run in to `ENOSPC` when their filesystem doesn't support file watching, which Cypress uses to keep track of file changes.

If you're on Linux, you can try increasing the number of file watchers available:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```